# Android ScrollView height not changing

Tags: android, android-layout, height, scrollview

I have a layout with the following XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myEditLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/myEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dip"
                android:paddingRight="8dip"
                android:maxLines="300"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:hint="Type notes here..."
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutKbd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
               android:id="@+id/myKeyboardView"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:focusable="true"
               android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
               android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/kbdpreview"
               android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The top view is RelativeLayout with a ScrollView for the main content (which contains an EditText) and custom keyboard view. The custom keyboard pops up when the user clicks on the EditText.

It works perfectly for most part, but if the text being entered in the EditText is large, it gets covered by the custom keyboard view. So at that time, I need to adjust the ScrollView's height. I did it in the following manner:

```
// Activity's onCreate implementation
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditLinearLayout);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(m_tw);

    ...
}

private TextWatcher m_tw = new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    // This function returns if the custom keyboard is visible
    if (m_customKeyboard.isCustomKeyboardVisible())
    {
        int kbdHeight = m_customKeyboard.mKeyboardView.getHeight();
        int editTextBottom = m_editText.getBottom();
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollview);

        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting scrollview height = " + (editTextBottom + kbdHeight + 20));
        scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        Log.d(TAG, "Old scroll bounds: left = " + scrollBounds.left + " right = " + scrollBounds.right + " top = " + scrollBounds.top + " bottom = " + scrollBounds.bottom);

        scrollView.getLayoutParams().height = editTextBottom + kbdHeight + 20;

        Log.d(TAG, "Setting scrollview height = " + (editTextBottom + kbdHeight + 20));
        scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        Log.d(TAG, "New scroll bounds: left = " + scrollBounds.left + " right = " + scrollBounds.right + " top = " + scrollBounds.top + " bottom = " + scrollBounds.bottom);
    }
    }
};
```

The above does not work. It shows the same value for scrollBounds.bottom, before and after setting scrollView height.

What am I missing?

Comment: i believe you can solve this entirely in your layout file by having the custom keyboard xml incorporate the layout_below attribute.

Comment: @radix, I think that is not the correct way. As the ScrollView is not fixed and then the keyboard might not be parent bottom.

Comment: @user2346980 I agree, my idea was to demonstrate that this is more of a UI change than code. OP can modify it as per his need and requirement.

Comment: I am not sure I understand Radix's suggestion. @Radix, do you mind explaining with the aid of example code?

Comment: A variation of this suggestion worked. I ended up setting andoid:layout_below attribut to the custom keyboard, and then whenever showing the custom keyboard, I set the scrollview height to (keyboardBottom - keyboardHeight). This works like a charm!

Comment: @Abhijit i see you have a working solution now. I would have given an example but what i wanted to point you to was that this is a problem thats related to the layout xml code. Anyways its solved for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the property

```
android:layout_above="@+id/yourKeyboardLayout"
```

in your scrollview.

Comment: Thank you. A variation of this suggestion worked. I ended up setting andoid:layout_below attribut to the custom keyboard, and then whenever showing the custom keyboard, I set the scrollview height to (keyboardBottom - keyboardHeight). This works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your manifest.  If you don't like the result, perhaps you can use some other pan.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Add this
>   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
>    in your manifest where activity is declare and you can also add in scroll view

Comment: This does not work. The manifest now has line 
 <activity
  android:name="..."
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateUnchanged|adjustResize|adjustPan"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_myedit"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:launchMode="singleTop" >
 </activity>

And ScrollView is defined as

 <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/myScrollview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  android:fillViewport="true" >

 ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change scrollview's LayoutParams, you should use the following code in you example:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = scrollView.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = editTextBottom + kbdHeight + 20;
scrollview.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. BTW, isn't this suggestion identical to what I already have? That is, what's the difference between this suggestion and scrollView.getLayoutParams().height = editTextBottom + kbdHeight + 20;